# adding multiple items to Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to write a todo note app, I have chosen redux to store a list of notes so every time the user adds a new note it will get added to a store. I want the store to be an array so I can after mapStateToProps and map over the store to list the notes.

The problem that I have is that every time I add a new Note it overrides the old one and the store does not keep an array list of all the notes.

My Form:

```
    import React ,{ useState } from "react";
    import './AddNoteForm.scss';
    import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import { setNoteData } from '../../actions';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';


    function AddNoteForm (props) {

        const [titleData, setTitleData] = useState('');
        const [noteData, setNewNoteData] = useState('');

        const { handleClose, setNoteData } = props;

//EDITED
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        setNoteData({title: titleData, note: noteData});
        handleClose();
    } 

        return (
            <div className="AddNoteForm">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                    <div className="AddNoteForm__title">
                        <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" value={titleData} onChange={(e) => setTitleData(e.target.value) } />
                    </div>
                    <div className="AddNoteForm__note">
                        <label htmlFor="note">Note</label>
                        <textarea type="text" name="note" value={noteData} onChange={(e) => setNewNoteData(e.target.value)} />
                    </div>
                    <Button className="AddNoteForm__button" variant="primary" type="submit">
                        Add
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }


    const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
        return {
            setNoteData,
        }
    }

    export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps())(AddNoteForm);
```

My Action:

```
export const SET_NOTE = 'SET_NOTE';
export const GET_NOTES = 'GET_NOTES';

export function setNoteData (note) {
    debugger;
    return {
        type: SET_NOTE,
        note
    }
}

//EDITED
my Reducer:

import { SET_NOTE } from '../actions';

const setNoteReducer = (state=[], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_NOTE:
            return state.concat([action.note]);
        default:
            return state    
    }
}
```

export default setNoteReducer;Redux console tracking:

[image]

As you can see I have called the SET_NOTE action twice which is triggered in my form in 'handleSubmit' but the previous state gets overridden by the new state they don't persist. Also, I am new to react Hooks and not sure I am using it correctly but when I debug it seems it does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should add the new received note into the array of notes in reducer not in your component.
2. Your reducer should be something like this:

```js
function noteReducer(state, action){
   switch(action.type){
      case "SET_NOTE":
        return state.concat([action.note]);
      default:
        return state;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey this seemed to work :) I have also made some changes in my handleSubmit changed it to a object with some meaningful keys rather than [0], [1] I have also tried .push instead concat and that didnt work wonder why

Comment: You don't need to push anything to the notes list in your component, you just have to dispatch the new note text and reducer will concatenate new text with older texts.

Answer (score 0):

Modify switch like following

```
switch (action.type) {
    case SET_NOTE:
        let new_state = state.push(action.note)
        return Object.assign(state, newState)
    default:
        return state    
}
```